# Installing Jetty on a debian 9 but Unit jetty.service not found

Tags: command-line, debian, installation, jetty

I'm trying to install Jetty on my Debian via SSH. I installed MySQL too (this is working).

For that, I follow this http://zetcode.com/java/jetty/install/

Instead of : 
`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless`, I install `sudo apt-get installed openjdk-8-jre-headless`

Instead of : `sudo wget http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/dist/jetty-distribution-9.2.3.v20140905.tar.gz`

, I installed : sudo wget `http://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.9.v20160517/dist/jetty-distribution-9.3.9.v20160517.tar.gz`

Then, When I should start Jetty with this command : `sudo service jetty start`

I received : `Failed to start jetty.service: Unit jetty.service not found.`

I don't understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of service is `jetty9.service` , you can check the status through :

```
sudo service jetty9 status
```

or

```
sudo systemctl status jetty9.service
```

To start the service:

```
sudo systemctl start jetty9.service
```

The [`jetty9`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/jetty9) package is availaible on debian stretch repository and it can be installed through `apt`

```
sudo apt install jetty9
```

Comment: but seems I have two jetty install now... and I'm not able to deploy my war, see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848086/error-404-when-i-try-to-deploy-my-war-on-jetty-on-debian-9