# Error 404 when I try to deploy my war on Jetty on Debian 9

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jetty, http-status-code-404, war

I'm trying to deploy my java web site on a Debian online server. For that, I install Jetty (following this : http://zetcode.com/java/jetty/install/)

Jetty seems to be ok on the server because when I enter http://myipaddress:8080. I have the "Welcome to Jetty".

Then, I use Filezilla to upload my war on the server. 
I compile my war with Eclipse and Maven :

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>test</name>
```

I compile it with mvn clean package. I had my war file. 
And I put it on the server :
[image]

I tried to put it in opt/jetty/webapps and opt/web/mam/webapps

But when I tried to access to my web site by doing http://myipaddress/test, I received a 404 error.

And I tried my command line with the curl command, I received an 404 error too.

I know it's basic, but I'm blocked..

How can I be sure that my war is ok? How can I be sure that my jetty configuration is ok?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by deleting the jetty installation and reinstall it. I put my WAR in the opt/jetty/webapps.